# Turn on brace / block indent lines in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I know some IDE's support this feature, but does anyone know how to activate brace lines?  I don't know exactly what they're called, but they look kinda like this:

```
if(numOfSomething > 8)
{
|   if(blah == true)
|   {
|   |    blah = false;
|   |    //whatever
|   }
{
```

Anyone know is visual studio supports these and how to turn them on?

Answer (score 1):

I have "Indent Guides" extension for that behaviour you say:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30